# For loop syntax?

Tags: bash

I'm just learning to code with bash, and I'm running into some problems doing some exercises. I feel like I might be doing something wrong with the syntax, but no matter how I look at it it doesn't look wrong.

The code I've got here is supposed to find the 'lucky numbers' between 1000 and 10000. In this case, a lucky number is a number who's digits sum to a number that in turns sums to 7. The part that does the calculation of the lucky number works on it's own, but once I put it into a for loop, where there is no single input, the output is infinite and wrong. I can only assume the for loop is the problem:

```
digit=0
sum=0
for (( i=1000; i<=10000; i++ ))
do
     while [ $i -gt 0 ]
     do
          digit=$(( $i % 10 ))
          i=$(( $i / 10 ))
          sum=$(( $sum + $digit ))
    done
    while [ $sum -gt 0 ]
    do
          digit=$(( $sum % 10 ))
          sum$(( $sum / 10 ))
          sum2=$(( $sum2 + $digit ))
    done
    if [[ $sum2 == 7 ]];
    then
          echo $sum2
    fi
done
```

If anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong, or even a way to make it better, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: What is the intended meaning of this line:  `sum$(( $sum ? 10 ))`.  I'm assuming that's a copy/paste error.

Comment: `1<=10000` is always true.

Comment: A good question isolates a single, specific problem, and removes everything but the minimum amount of code needed to demonstrate that problem. See http://sscce.org/ or http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You're also changing `i` inside the loop, which is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah... @kaitoy is right. It should be `i<=10000`.

Comment: Should it be `sum=$(( $sum / 10 ))`?

Answer (score 1):

```
i=$(( $i / 10 ))
```

You're modifying the `for` loop's variable. Don't do that; make a copy.

Answer (score 1):

> for (( i=1000; i<=10000; i++ ))

If you want to learn bash for bash's sake, every last nook and cranny, that's fine, but I suggest you focus your attention on portable Bourne shell syntax.

- It works in bash, and it has worked for millions of programmers for decades.  Very often, the Old Ways are good ways.
- You will encounter non-bash code in a variety of circumstances.

Most Linux systems include **seq**(1).  So these work:

```
$ for i in $(seq 1000 10000); do echo $i; done | wc -l
9001
$ seq 1000 10000 | while read i; do echo $i; done | wc -l
9001
```

Shell scripts usually iterate over some input (a list of filenames, say) not for *N* times.  I guess `seq` was invented to support counted loops before bash developed the counted-loop syntax.

As a by-product of using `seq`, I think your loop body will work unaltered.  Because the loop (while or for) is assigning `i` from its input from `seq`, whatever you do to `i` in the body is lost at the next iteration.

Comment: You could also `for i in {1000..10000}; do ...`.